# How to pass correct object value in SqlParameter for datatype bit?

Tags: c#, sqlparameter

I am trying to pass a bit value only if needed (is checked).

How do I do this correctly? I am not getting a change in my dataset. SQL Server 2008.

```
if (chkExpired.Checked)
    CmdGetDetails.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@isExpired", 1));
```

Comment: You should include more info. What is your database platform? Where is the rest of your query?

Comment: `isExpired` looked like boolean field, represented as `bit` in SQL Server. Are you sure you have an `int` field

Comment: I need to cast that 1 int value dont I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`bit` refers to `Boolean`

so you would pass a boolean value in parameter's value

Ex :

```
CmdGetDetails.Parameters.AddWithValue("isExpired", chkExpired.Checked);
```

There is no addtional need to use a if block.

Comment: that way will return only checked value not both checked or unchecked... what I really need is to pass the chosen value

Answer (score 3):

```
            param.ParameterName = "@isExpired";
            param.Value =chkExpired.Checked; 
            param.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Boolean;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: that way will return only checked value not both checked or unchecked... what I really need is to pass the chosen value

Answer (score 1):

Just use the value of your checkbox (`chkExpired.Checked`):

```
CmdGetDetails.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@isExpired", chkExpired.Checked));
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to add the parameter either way, as a boolean :

```
CmdGetDetails.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@isExpired", chkExpired.Checked));
```

Comment: that way will return only checked value not both checked or unchecked... what I really need is to pass the chosen value